# Why am I getting a tensors with different shapes error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to build an LSTM model for text generation and I am getting an error when trying to fit the model.

Traceback:

`> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found. (0) Invalid argument:  Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [21] and element 1 had shape [17]. [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at tmp/ipykernel_7804/4234150290.py:1) ]] (1) Invalid argument:  Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [21] and element 1 had shape [17]. [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at tmp/ipykernel_7804/4234150290.py:1) ]] [[IteratorGetNext/_4]] 0 successful operations. 0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_35783]`

Code:

```
    batch_size = 64
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    buffer_size= train_ds.cardinality().numpy()
    
    train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)\
                       .batch(batch_size=batch_size,drop_remainder=True)\
                       .cache()\
                       .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    
    test_ds = test_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)\
                       .batch(batch_size=batch_size,drop_remainder=True)\
                       .cache()\
                       .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)

    def create_model():
        n_units = 256
        max_len = 64
        vocab_size = 10000
        
        inputs_tokens = Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32)
        # inputs_tokens = Input(shape = (None,), dtype=tf.int32)
        
        embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 256)
        x = embedding_layer(inputs_tokens)
        x = LSTM(n_units)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
        outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation = 'softmax')(x)
        model = Model(inputs=inputs_tokens, outputs=outputs)
        
        loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
        metric_fn  = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
        model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=loss_fn, metrics=metric_fn)  
        
        return model
```

When I look at the type specification train_ds.element_spec I get:

```
    (TensorSpec(shape=<unknown>, dtype=tf.int64, name=None),
     TensorSpec(shape=(64,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Should I be using padded_batch? Should I reshape my dataset?

EDIT:

How I am creating `train_ds`:

I have an array of `~100k` lyrics as strings in a list like so:
`

> [' mic check, i can get smooth to any groove ',
> ' relax the tongue, let my mic take a cruise ',
> " around the planet, pack 'em in like janet ",]`

I use `train_test_split` to create test and training sets for features and labels where the label is the 2nd to the last word in each bar.

```
    train_text_ds_raw = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
                tf.cast(train_data.values, tf.string)
    ) 
    
    train_cat_ds_raw = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
                tf.cast(train_targets.values, tf.int64),
    
    )
```

Then I created this function:

```
    vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_features,
        # standardize=lyrics_corpus,
        split="whitespace",
        ngrams=2,
        output_mode="int",
        # output_sequence_length=max_len,
        # vocabulary=words,
    )

    def convert_text_input(sample):
        text = sample
        text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)  
        return tf.squeeze(vectorize_layer(text))
```

apply function

```
    train_text_ds = train_text_ds_raw.map(convert_text_input, 
                                      num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

put label and text back together

```
    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        (
                train_text_ds,
                train_cat_ds_raw
         )
    )
```

Example Table
|       | predictor | label                                             | label_id |
|-----------|---------------------------------------------------|----------|-------|
| 0         |  mic check, i can get smooth to any groov... | groove   | 8167  |
| 1         |  relax the tongue, let my mic take a crui... | cruise   | 4692  |
| 2         |  around the planet, pack 'em in like jane... | janet    | 9683  |
| 3         |  jackson, she's askin' if i can slam it, ... | i'm—     | 9191  |
| 4         |  yo, yo, redman, man, what the fuck, man?... | man?     | 11174 |

Comment: Can you show how you are creating your dataset `train_ds`?

Comment: added as an edit

Comment: Thanks and train_targets.values are what exactly? Integers ?

Comment: Integer encodings for the labels (the labels are the second to last word in each line)

Comment: do you have a link to your dataset

Comment: I added an example of the table the markdown shows properly in the edit but looks off here. I have the lyric, the label, and the label_id in a dataframe.